# Need async entrypoint for custom configuration of DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Net Core and EF core does not support AAD tokens out of the box like full framework. There are a workaroudn were you can set access token on the SqlConnection. Retrieving the token is a async operation. So I need a generic entrypoint that are async. In constructor of my DbContext I can inject and execute stuff, but I cant do it async so it not good enough.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
internal class DbTokenConfig : IDbContextConfig
{
    private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public DbTokenConfig(ITokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    public async Task Config(MyDbContext context)
    {
        var conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection() as SqlConnection;
        conn.AccessToken = await _tokenProvider.GetAsync();
    }
}
```

I need a async entrypoint were I can execute it, generic offcourse so any service that inject a DbContext will get it applied

edit: So basicly when doing

```
public class MyCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<MyCommand> 
{
   private readonly DbContext _ctx;

   public MyCommandHandler(DbContext ctx) 
   {
      _ctx = ctx;
   }

   public async Task Handle(MyCommand cmd) 
   {
      await _ctx.Set<Foo>().ToListAsync(); //I want my access token to be applied before it opens connection
   }
}
```

edit: Working solution

```
.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(b => b.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDb")))
.AddScoped<DbContext>(p =>
{
    var ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx");
    var result = ctx.AcquireTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/", new ClientCredential("xxx", "xxx"))
        .ConfigureAwait(false)
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();

    var db = p.GetService<MyDbContext>();
    ((SqlConnection)db.Database.GetDbConnection()).AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
    return db;
})
```

Just need to make the keys configurable, create a abstraction etc

Comment: Your question is very broad/generic. In one statement you mention how retrieving a token is an async operation, then another statement where you say you need a generic entry point which is async. An application only has one entry point, what exactly is that that you want to achieve?

Comment: Updated question again, I offcourse talk about a entrypoint within EF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [a Github issue about this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11928#issuecomment-387420827), so this is definitely not unclear. The issue is closed because there's no built-in support currently, a [different issue tracks this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13261).

The original issue describes a clever workaround though. First of all, `UseSqlBuilder` has an overload that accepts an existing DbConnection. This connection can be configured with an AAD token. If it's closed, EF will open and close it as needed. One could write :

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration["ConnectionString"]);
            conn.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/")
                        .Result;
            options.UseSqlServer(conn);
});
```

The tricky part is how to dispose that connection.

The clever solution posted by Brian Ball is to implement an interface on the DbContext, and register *that* as the service that's used by controllers with a factory function. The DbContext still gets registered using its concrete type. The factory function gets that context and sets the AAD token to its connection :

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext>(serviceProvider => {
  //Get the configured context
  var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();  

  //And set the AAD token to its connection
  var connection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection() as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
  if(connection == null) {/*either return dbContext or throw exception, depending on your requirements*/}
  connection.AccessToken = //code used to acquire an access token;

  return dbContext;
});
```

This way, the context's lifetime is still managed by EF Core. `AddScoped<IMyDbContext>` acts as a filter that takes that context and sets the AAD token

Next problem is how to write that `//code used to acquire an access token;` so it doesn't block.

This isn't so much of a problem because, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication) :

> The AzureServiceTokenProvider class caches the token in memory and retrieves it from Azure AD just before expiration.

This code could be extracted into a factory method, and even get injected as a dependency.

**Moving the goal posts**

The main problem is that constructors can't be asynchronous *yet* so constructor injection can't retrieve tokens asynchronously.

What *can* be done though, is to register an asynchronous `Func<>` factory or service that's called in a controller's asynchronous actions instead of the constructor. Let's say :

```
//Let's inject configuration too
//Defaults stolen from AzureServiceTokenProvider's source
public class TokenConfig
{
    public string ConnectionString {get;set;};    
    public string AzureAdInstance {get;set;} = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";

    public string TennantId{get;set;}
    public string Resource {get;set;}
}

class DbContextWithAddProvider
{
    readonly AzureServiceTokenProvider _provider;
    readonly TokenConfig _config;
    readonly IServiceProvider _svcProvider;

    public DbContextWithAddProvider(IServiceProvider svcProvider, IOption<TokenConfig> config)
    {
        _config=config;
        _provider=new AzureServiceTokenProvider(config.ConnectionString,config.AzureAdInstance);
        _svcProvider=svcProvider;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetContextAsync<T>() where T:DbContext
    {
        var token=await _provider.GetAccessTokenAsync(_config.Resource,_config.TennantId);
        var dbContext = _svcProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();  

        var connection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection() as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
        connection.AccessToken = token;
        return dbContext;
    }
}
```

This service should be registered as a singleton as it doesn't keep any state except the cached token, which we *do* want to keep around.

This can now be injected in a constructor, and called in an async action :

```
class MyController:Controller
{
    DbContextWithAddProvider _ctxProvider;

    public MyController(DbContextWithAddProvider ctxProvider)
    {
        _ctxProvider=ctxProvider;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var dbCtx=await _ctxProvider.GetContextAsync<MyDbContext>();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Really sad there isnt any async solution. Since this will put strain on the system. But I guess maybe its fine since most of the time it will be a in memory cache fetch

Comment: @Anders there *is* an async solution. The hard part is separating the token and DbContext operations. Once you do this you don't have to read the token directly. You could read it during startup and cache it yourself.  You could put that code behind another service and use eg a Lazy<T> to ensure it's asynchronously initialized when needed. I'd use a separate service anyway to hide the `AzureServiceTokenProvider`. As the docs say, the provider is acting as a lazy cache itself, so the only time there's a delay is during refreshes

Comment: @Anders in the general case, the wider problem is  asynchronous dependency injection. This can't be solved with .NET Core's DI *yet*, because constructors can't be asynchronous *yet*. The controller that accepts that DbContext can't be asynchronous itself, so it can't benefit from an asynchronously injected DbContext either.

Comment: @Anders what you *can* do, is register an asynchronous factory method, inject that in the controller and call it inside asynchronous actions. The downside to this is that the rest of the middleware can't see that DbContext any more, which can be a problem if eg you want to add auditing or change connections in a middleware.

Comment: I posted my final solution

Comment: @Anders I also posted another idea - move all of this into a factory service and only call it inside asynchronous actions. It's more complex so you'll have to decide whether the complexity is justified.

Comment: I dont want to change my domain. Its really sad that they dont have a async enetrypoint. I mean it could be called as part of the async call to ToListAsync or similar.

Comment: Actuallty I haver my own entry point in the domain I could use, but then it wouldnt work if someone used the DbContext directly outside of domain

Answer (score 1):

I went through a similar though process almost 2 years ago where, in my last job, we decided to implement dynamic refreshing of the credentials for a `DbContext` object which it retrieved from Key Vault on the applications initial startup and then cached the credentials, if a connection failed then it was assumed that the credentials had changed or expired and it would retrieve them again and refresh the `SqlConnection` object (happy-path scenario, obviously there are other reasons for a connection to fail).

The problem then, and in this case, is that `IServiceCollection` has no asynchronous method available which allow you to invoke asynchronous delegates, so you have to use `.Result` when registering a service with asynchronous logic as a prerequisite.

What you could do is create a `SqlConnection` object with your access token and pass that to `SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer` within the `AddDbContext<T>` service registration in `ConfigureServices`. This ensures that every `DbContext` which is created will have an access token assigned, and with it being scoped by default it will have a new token per request.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.AddScoped<ITokenProvider, TokenProvider>();
    services.AddScoped<ISqlConnectionProvider, SqlConnectionProvider>();

    services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>((provider, options) =>
    {
        var connectionTokenProvider = provider.GetService<ITokenProvider>();
        var sqlConnectionProvider = provider.GetService<ISqlConnectionProvider>();

        var accessToken = connectionTokenProvider.GetAsync().Result; // Yes, I consider this to be less than elegant, but marking this delegate as async & awaiting would result in a race condition.
        var sqlConnection = sqlConnectionProvider.CreateSqlConnection(accessToken);

        options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnection);
    });
}
```

The interface for `ISqlConnectionProvider` is

```
internal interface ISqlConnectionProvider
{
    SqlConnection CreateSqlConnection(string accessToken);
}
```

In the implementation of `ISqlConnectionProvider` you'd have to

1. Inject an `IOptions<T>` object which contains the connection string details
2. Build or assign the connection string
3. Assign the access token
4. Return the `SqlConnection` object

Comment: According to the docs, AzureServiceTokenProvider caches the token so `.Result` will return the cached token most of the time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure if OP is using Key Vault for his token retrieval, but otherwise that is good to know info knowing it saves some round trips on network latency as well as application performance.

Comment: `AzureServiceTokenProvider` is separate from Key Vault. [The documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication) shows how to use the provider with or without they Key Vault. Once again, merging two different concepts in the same doc page .......

Comment: On a quick glance, I can see there isn't even an MSDN API page for `AzureServiceTokenProvider` other than the docs you linked to, at least I know my confusion wasn't from an overabundance or lack of caffeine.